# How to change make the first row (include the column name) into one entry

Tags: r

For example the original dataset is this

[image: example]

i want the result to be

for the first row (one entry)

```
Arson: 133  
Assault/battery: 11330  
Bomb/guns: 604
```

for the second row (one entry)

```
Arson: 152  
Assault/battery: 10090  
Bomb/guns: 156
```

i want to change to this

Comment: can you use `dput` to show the example.  I am guessing you want to `paste` the columns with the column name

Comment: Can you try `library(dplyr);library(tidyr);library(stringr);dat1 %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% pivot_longer(cols = -rn) %>% unite(keyval, name, value, sep = ": ")%>% group_by(rn) %>% summarise(keyval = str_c(keyval, collapse = "\n"))`

Comment: I want to make the  column names and first row into one entry like the only one column but first row will be 'Arson:133, Assault/battery:11330, Bomb/guns: 604, crime against child: 504' and then second row will be: 'Arson:152, Assault/battery:10090, Bomb/guns: 156, crime against child: 113' so on

Comment: Try the code above

Comment: I thought your columns are all numeric as you showed in the image

Comment: it works, thanks! but the new line

Comment: I used `\n` as separator based on the output you showed.  If you do `cat`, it will show in next line

Comment: Thanks! there is Error in `n()`:
! Must be used inside dplyr verbs.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Try the other solution I posted.  Your error assumes that you may have some functions got masked.  Try it on a fresh session with only the packages I showed or use `::` with namespace as `dplyr::summarise`, `dply::transmute`

Answer (score 0):

We may loop `across` the columns of interest, `paste` (`str_c`) the column name (`cur_column()`) with the values in the column, then `unite` the columns into a single column with `sep = ", "` (or if we need new line use (`\n`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
dat1 %>%
   transmute(across(Arson:`Crimes against children`,
     ~ str_c(cur_column(), ": ", .x))) %>% 
   unite(keyval, everything(), sep = ", ", na.rm = TRUE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 1
  keyval                                                                          
  <chr>                                                                           
1 Arson: 133, Assault/battery: 11330, Bomb/guns: 604, Crimes against children: 504
2 Arson: 152, Assault/battery: 10090, Bomb/guns: 156, Crimes against children: 113
```

#### data

```
dat1 <- structure(list(Arson = c(133, 152), `Assault/battery` = c(11330, 
10090), `Bomb/guns` = c(604, 156), `Crimes against children` = c(504, 
113)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```